# The done() not calls in async.eachSeries method in async.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have an array of links (more than 100 links) and i make the requests to these links in async.eachSeries function. Simple Example

```
async.eachSeries(links, function iterator(link, callback) {
  request(link, function(err,res){
    callback(err, res);
   })
}, function done() {
  console.log('finished');
});
```

But when i received data of all links, the message 'finished' are not shown. Could you explain me, why? And how to fix this issue.

Comment: seem to miss a ')' at the end of the request method.

Comment: I missed ")" when wrote question.

Comment: I tried the code and it works !

Comment: This is not detailed example. Please try it with calls to real API and passing data to callback.

Comment: Add some more `console.log` lines, especially inside the `function iterator()`. If you got 100 links, and even 2 of them time out, you could be waiting a while. Is every request being made? Are they all returning?

Comment: All requests are done.